# ActiveAdmin to filter float fields on ActiveRecord models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activeadmin

I found [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info) very useful for creating rather full-brown scaffold for our ActiveRecord models. However, our models have float (and some decimal) columns and ActiveAdmin fails to create filters for them.

For example,

```
ActiveAdmin.register ForexRate do
  filter :rate, :as => :numeric
end
```

gives me NoMethodError, saying

```
undefined method `rate_gt' for #<MetaSearch::Searches::ForexRate:0x007fa4427bb018>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

P.S. I have confirmed the same filter worked for integer columns.

Comment: what is your sql type for column rate ?

Comment: In SQLite3 the `rate` column is on `REAL`. (I know it has to be `DECIMAL` but)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was from my table having `rate` as `REAL` instead of `FLOAT` or `DECIMAL(x,y)`. Changing it to either FLOAT or DECIMAL fixed the issue.

It is also interesting to observe that, when the column is REAL, or other unrecognizable type, ActiveRecord::Base#inspect becomes:

```
>> ForexRate
=> ForexRate(id: integer, created_at: timestamp, updated_at: timestamp, rate:  , from: string, to:string)
```

(Notice the blank next to `rate:`)

Answer (score 0):

Quickly looking at the [source](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/filters/forms.rb#L29), it would seems your doing it right.  I've done this myself, without issue. By default, ActiveAdmin should catch floats and apply a numeric filter to them.  Have you tried not specifying `:as => :numeric` and seeing if that works?  Can you confirm storing your fields in the DB as floats and not as strings? Finally, are referencing a column that does exist and is named properly??

Comment: I have tried removing `:as => :numeric`, confirmed `rate` is `REAL`, column exists and named propery. ActiveRecord actually loads rows and `ForexRate#rate` was `Float`. Strange...